# Append a variable to a file in Python

Tags: python

I have created a hangman game in python, I will post the code in a bit. I have variables in the code such as lives left and the word which the user is trying to guess. What I want to do is then once the game is over and the user has either won or lost I want the results of that game to be printed to a text file so the user can look and see what the word was and how many lives they had left. The words that could be used as the word to guess are currently been read from a text file called hangman.txt as you will see in the code.

```
import random
guessed_letters = ''
lives_remaining = 15
turns = 10


try:
    f = open('hangman.txt', 'r')
    words = f.read().splitlines()
    f.close()

except IOError:
    print("Error, file does not exist")
    exit()

a = open('results.txt', 'w')
a.write('the resulst of hangman are')
a.close()

def pick_a_word():
    wordposition=random.randint(0,len(words)-1)
    return words[wordposition]
word = pick_a_word()
length = len(word)
print "word is", length,
print ("letters long")
print '_ ' * length

def get_guess():
    guess = raw_input('Guess a letter')
    return guess

guesses = ''
turns = 15
used = []

while turns > 0:
    failed = 0

    for char in word:
        if char in guesses:
            print char,

        else:
            print "_",
            failed += 1

    if failed == 0:
        print "you won"

        break
    print

    guess = raw_input("guess a character:")

    guesses += guess

    if guess not in word:

        turns -= 1
        print "wrong"

        print "you have", + turns, 'more guesses'

        if turns == 0:

            print "You loose"

b = open('results.txt', 'a')
b.write('the new word was' + word + 'The lives you had left were:' + turns)
b.close()
```

The code is currently running fine until the game is over and then this error message is printed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Hangman/hangmanAppend.py", line 75, in <module>
    b.write('the new word was' + word + 'The lives you had left were:' + turns)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: python 101: `str(turns)`. Did you read the error?

Comment: and lose the `+` in `print "you have", + turns, 'more guesses'` -- it's a prefix operator doing nothing, and only confuses things:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`turns` contains an **integer** and cannot be concatenated to a **string**. Only a **string** can be concatenated with other **string**. So you need to convert `turns` to **string** as `str(turns)`. So:

Replace:

```
b.write('the new word was' + word + 'The lives you had left were:' + turns)
```

with:

```
b.write('the new word was' + word + 'The lives you had left were:' + str(turns))
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll up vote your answer once I get enough reputation haha

Answer (score 1):

```
b.write('the new word was' + word + 'The lives you had left were:' + str(turns))
```

will get your job done!!

Answer (score 0):

variable word has string type and turns has int type that why you are getting these error.

change the line to ...

```
b.write('the new word was' + word + 'The lives you had left were:' + str(turns))
```

it will convert the variable turn into string type and then you can concat them.